# What is the most efficient way in terms of energy/costs to implement a hash lookup for data using c# and .net core?

Tags: c#, database, microservices, lookup

There is a hash table where we need to lookup for data from time to time, it is pretty big - compressed key-value pairs are about 1Gb. The service will be runnign as docker image in the cloud, and has possibility to use external database. Our goal is to minimize the energy/costs impact of this service.

Is there any research-analysis of what would be the most efficient way to implement such a service using c#/.net core and running on kubernetes:

1. Load the data into memory and lookup there? Process takes about 4-5Gb of memory, slow start
2. Use an established db like sql server - traffic, additional costs for sql server
3. Lookup in the flat file on the disk - presumably slow unless there is a good library somehow optimizing the search

I know it is pretty out of the ordinary question, but any feedback is appreatiated and would help to design better micro services (saving energy will become critical on a short run).

Comment: I'm assuming read-only data. A fully in-memory table will always be fastest, and is also simple to implement. You could use LevelDB if the data doesn't fit in RAM; it's a very efficient on-disk key-value store with compression built in. Or use SQLite if you need to index on multiple fields or other such flexibility.

Comment: Yes, it is a read only access, hash can be updated, but very low frequency aand we can always restart the servcie when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

re "established db" - a RDBMS like SQL Server would seem massively overkill here, but you should maybe consider things like redis or memcached

However, I'd probably want to look at [FASTER](https://microsoft.github.io/FASTER/) - which is sort of both of the "2" and "3" thing here, but allowing an in-process server with access to the persistent storage. Other in-process KV stores will be readily available. If you wanted to implement "3" by hand, you'd probably want to look at memory-mapped files and advanced indexing techniques.